# What is the best way to steam MongoDB data to the client for large applications?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux, react-redux, marketplace

I am having trouble scaling my react application as our database collections increase in size. We are a physical products marketplace and the way we currently display our listings is by loading the whole 'listings' collection at once on redux through 1 http request and state update. That is highly inefficient as you need to load the whole 'listings' collection before doing anything on the website. Once it is loaded it is super fast at rendering any page since the whole DB data is stored in redux. Though that takes more than 30s to load the whole collection at times!

My question: is there a way to open an HTTP stream or similar with MongoDB atlas so that I can render listings dynamically by updating the redux state as they come through from the server?

Is there any other way to achieve faster load speed by still leveraging react-redux?

What's the best practice with data heavy SPAs?

We have an express, node js back end with react front end. Using MongoDB for storage. React-redux to share states between components. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not familiar with MongoDB atlas, but they probably have some opinions/recommendations on caching? Letting every browser hit the DB directly on first page load is probably slow as you described. Some kind of cache is needed in front of that. To your idea about streaming DB changes to the SPA as they happen: Probably possible (web socket?) but I don't think you'd want that. Causes lots of traffic to replicate the DB 1:1 in the browser, but the user might not be looking at the updated products at the moment. Definitely check out redux-toolkit, they have some machinery for doing cache-first redux.

Comment: About achieving faster load speed: If you don't want to go the full server-side-rending route (Next.js etc.), a common solution is to bootstrap the data into the index.html of your SPA. I.e. letting some build script periodically inject a `<script>var reduxInitialState = {...};</script>` into the html. This way there is always at least some data to display right away, even though it might be a bit outdated and the refresh takes a bit longer.